# How to get user id from Firebase Auth in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I want to save user-related data in Firestore by assigning user id to a document as a field.

**How to get user id from Firebase Auth?**

**Or is there a better way to store user data in Firestore?**

I couldn't get user id from Firebase Auth in this way (the Text(_userId) returns _userId == null error):

```
String _userId;
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      _userId = user.uid;
    });

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("App bar"),
      ),
      body: new Text(_userId),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`_userId` is null because the widgets are being built before the Future returned by `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` has completed. Once it does complete it's too late and the widgets don't update. One way to work with it would be to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) somewhat like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("App bar"),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.uid);
        }
        else {
          return Text('Loading...');
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Current User Id:

```
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid
```

##### To store user details in the `uid`:

Use `set()` method:

```
final user = <String, String>{
  "name": "Mohan Roy",
  "state": "CA",
  "country": "USA"
};

Firestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .set(user)
    .onError((e, _) => print("Error writing document: $e"));
```

---

#### Extra:

##### Current User Name:

```
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName
```

##### Current User Email:

```
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email
```

##### Current User Phone Number:

```
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.phoneNumber
```